# Creating a Marquee-like effect with a TextBlock in XAML

Tags: xaml, overflow, textblock, marquee

I have a TextBlock in XAML, and I am trying to create a horizontally scrolling 'marquee' of text on a button. However, the TextBlock's width gets set to the width of the parent.

As an example, say we have this text inside the TextBlock:

> [The quick brown f]ox jumps over the lazy dog

i.e. Long text should appear as this:

> [The quick brown f]

but it is limited to the size of the parent this means that as it scrolls, the text is missing:

> [ick brown f    ] //Missing 'ox'

any ideas on how to force a TextBlock to ignore parent width?